# Why does Oracle Database Configuration failed on ubuntu?

Tags: linux, oracle, ubuntu

I'm trying to install Oracle Database 11g Express Edition on my ubuntu server. After running command:

```
sudo service oracle-xe start
```

I get following result after configuration:

```
Starting Oracle Net Listener...Done
Configuring database...
Database Configuration failed.  Look into /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/config/log for de                                                                              tails
```

in log files I found the following informations:

CloneRmanRestore.log:

```
    LRM-00116: syntax error at 'sessions' following '='
ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters
select TO_CHAR(systimestamp,'YYYYMMDD HH:MI:SS') from dual
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0


declare
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0


select TO_CHAR(systimestamp,'YYYYMMDD HH:MI:SS') from dual
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0
```

postDBCreation.log

```
begin
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0


create spfile='/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/dbs/spfileXE.ora' FROM pfile='/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/config/scripts/init.ora'
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters
LRM-00116: syntax error at 'sessions' following '='


ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist
Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory
ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters
LRM-00109: could not open parameter file '/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/dbs/initXE.ora'
select 'utl_recomp_begin: ' || to_char(sysdate, 'HH:MI:SS') from dual
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0


BEGIN utl_recomp.recomp_serial(); END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0


select 'utl_recomp_end: ' || to_char(sysdate, 'HH:MI:SS') from dual
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0
```

cloneDBCreation.log:

```
Create controlfile reuse set database "XE"
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0


BEGIN dbms_backup_restore.zerodbid(0); END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0


ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist
Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory
LRM-00116: syntax error at 'sessions' following '='
ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters
Create controlfile reuse set database "XE"
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0


alter system enable restricted session
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0


alter database "XE" open resetlogs
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0

postDBCreation.log:
begin
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0


create spfile='/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/dbs/spfileXE.ora' FROM pfile='/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/config/scripts/init.ora'
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters
LRM-00116: syntax error at 'sessions' following '='


ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist
Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory
ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters
LRM-00109: could not open parameter file '/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/dbs/initXE.ora'
select 'utl_recomp_begin: ' || to_char(sysdate, 'HH:MI:SS') from dual
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0


BEGIN utl_recomp.recomp_serial(); END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0


select 'utl_recomp_end: ' || to_char(sysdate, 'HH:MI:SS') from dual
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0
```

postScripts.log:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE LIBRARY dbms_sumadv_lib AS '/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/lib/libqsmashr.so';
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0


BEGIN dbms_datapump_utl.replace_default_dir; END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0


commit
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0


create or replace directory XMLDIR as '/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/rdbms/xml'
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0


DROP DIRECTORY ORACLE_OCM_CONFIG_DIR
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0


DROP DIRECTORY ADMIN_DIR
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
```

How can I fix it and configure my database? I have 256 MB of RAM memory, is it enough to run Oracle? Can it be an issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/install.112/e18802/toc.htm#XEINL102) says that 512Mb of RAM is recommended to run Oracle XE, with 256Mb minimum required. In reality, with anything else running on the Linux box/VM, you're really going to struggle with just 256Mb.

Make sure you've adhered to all of the pre-requisites in the documentation (kernel params, adding 2Gb of swap space) before you try and re-install.

I've successfully had it running on a Digital Ocean VM with 512Mb of RAM - I just added a 4Gb swap file on the disk - and it ran like a dream. Well, a slow dream :-)

Answer (score 1):

This error pops up during the installation of the `init.ora` files and other `initXE*` files that are in the folder:

```
/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/config/scripts
```

You need to edit these configurations, and look for the line that says:

```
MEMORY_TARGET =
```

If this is empty, like in the line above, we must add the memory we want to assign. in my case I put 1Gb in both files:

```
MEMORY_TARGET = 1G
```

After making this change in both files, you have to save it and run the Oracle configuration script again.

Normally everything should be fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Just had a similar problem. Tried the solutions given so far - here my 2 cents:
Ram and kernel parameters must be set correctly. These are my settings in `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
kernel.sem = 250 32000 100 128
fs.file-max = 6815744
kernel.shmmax=4294967295
kernel.shmmni=4096
kernel.shmall=2097152
```

Regarding the `initXE*` files in `u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/config/scripts`: setting `MEMORY_TARGET = 1G` didn't work for me. So I removed the line "MEMORY_TARGET =" alltogether (i.e. put a hash in front of it and transforming it to a comment). Installation worked ok without further glitches. Hurray!

Answer (score 0):

Commenting out `memory_target` in `init.ora` and `initXE.ora` worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Once I investigated the log files, I was able to notice that the `DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST` destination directory in `/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/config/scripts/init*` did not exist. So I manually created the directory.

In my case

```
sudo mkdir /u01/app/oracle/fast_recovery_area
```

This has been applied within both `init.ora` and `initXETemp.ora`.
Restarted the Laptop and started the configuration again.

`/etc/init.d/oracle-xe configure`

The above completed the configuration successfully for me.